# c# How can I properly serialize an Icon?

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I am trying to serialize a List of Icons into a cache file for later use.
With using BinaryFormatter for the serialization, it seems that the icons lose a lot of the quality when deserialized.

Is there a proper way of serializing Icons without losing any quality?

My code for the serialization and deserialization:

```
//Serialization  
List<Icon> icons = GetIcons(); //some function that gets the icons
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, icons);
}

//Deserialization
List<Icon> icons = new List<Icon>();
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    icons = (List<Icon>)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Comment: Call the `Save` method on each icon object to output the icon to a stream, then you can save that stream wherever you like. You can't just serialise aritrary classes.

Comment: Compare the input list and output list and see if there are exactly the same.  Then the issue is happening after the code posted.  The method you use to display the icon is causing the issue.

Comment: @jdweng That makes absolutely zero sense and is also plain wrong.

Comment: FYI: You [shouldn't be using BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide)

Comment: @DavidG : What is wrong with comparing input and output to debug and find root cause of issue?

Comment: @jdweng Because it's just not relevant to the problem here.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am using protobuf for all the classes in my app, I just wasn't sure how the Icon info is stored and since the documentation says it is serializable I tried with BinaryFormatter.